# how to open different listview on button click same activity

Tags: android

I want to open different listview on button click on same Activity. Button 1 will open listA button 2 will open listB and button3 will open listC. How can I do this?

Comment: have 3 listviews in your layout and keep visibility gone and on respective button click show the listview

Comment: Please show your efforts.

Comment: Seriously, do you want us to build an app for you?

Comment: Sorry for not showing the code

Comment: You can set OnClickListeners to your buttons and when they get clicked you just update the data of the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Give personal setOnClickListener event to all 3 buttons and open personal activities for showing listview on clicking 3 buttons and set adapters for all 3 listviews.

Comment: this is not an answer please post such things as comments. you have enough reputation for that

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use Activity(A) and contain ListView and when press item ListView open Activity(A) by new data and load again ListView.

Attention: read this Article [link](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-activity-launchmode-explained-cbc6cf996802)

```
launchMode=”standard”
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer